# UILabel Hidden text issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

Well this so weird . I also hesitate to post this question but I haven't got any solution that's why I decided to post it. Here I go.

I have a XIB i have subclassed it in UICollectionView. This is my code in didSelectMethod:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:0.8];

[cell setSelected:NO];

cell.nameLabel.hidden = NO;
cell.nameLabel.text = @"HHHHHHH";
cell.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
```

Now when I run my code I get correct Output. But when I select any `cell` then text of my `UILabel` is hidden I can only see the `background` colour.

When I select another one then I get back the text of previously selected `UILabel`.

I haven't written any other code I not able to figure it OUT.

When I select any cell:

[image]

When I select another cell:

[image]

When I select Previous Cell:

[image]

Here is my code for making cells:

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Get reusable cell reference
CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



[cell updateText];




return cell;
}
```

This method is in custom Class

```
 - (void) updateText{


self.nameLabel.text = name;

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your nib/xib file and check the highlighted color weather it is clear or some other color. If it is clear than change as per your requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Capture your selected index in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and reload you collection view. In `cellForIndexPath` check for your selected index and do the stuff there. Do some thing like below

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:0.8];

        [cell setSelected:NO];

        cell.nameLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.nameLabel.text = @"HHHHHHH";
        cell.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
       [collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @Bamsworld Edited. Thanks

Comment: I am facing same problem, by just writing reloadData in didSelectItemAtIndexpath solve the issue but i don't want to make a reloadData on every selection. I am taking control in Storyboard not creating it manually, is there any other way from which i can overcome this issue. please help

Answer (score 0):

It's high probably because your `CollectionViewCell` is reusable cell. You `hidden` state is reused for other cells too. You should set it in your `cellForIndexPath` method.

```
- (void)updateText
{
    self.nameLabel.text = name;
    cell.nameLabel.hidden = YES; // set here it's default value
}
```

Comment: did you implemet `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ?

Comment: Show your implementation

Comment: `UICollectionView` will reuse your previously used cell, so if you set your label to be hidden, then it'll be hidden for all other cell. You should create a array to store selected state of each cell, then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set your label hidden base on that array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Bool Array for each cell and then update the values when any cell is selected i.e in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.
Also inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, you can go as quoted by Vijay except just taking in consideration only one selected cell you can now handle multiple selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that you should have set highlighted color of label to clear color in xib unknowingly. Check your nib and change **highlighted property** to desired color you want. When a cell is selected the subviews changes their color to their highlighted color set in xib. Hope this will help you. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4jWF.png)